# Can't add useQuery to a function => Invalid Hook and "not a function" Error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, apollo-client

I'm a React-newbie.

I would like to include data from a graphql DB via apollo-client. As soon as I add the useQuery constant I get the following error:

> Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

and

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'useContext' of null

and

> TypeError: getDocumentProps is not a function

Code:

```
export function getDocumentProps(pageProps) {

    const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(getMetaData, {
      variables: { blockname: "MetaData" },
    });
  
    if (loading) return "";
    if (error) return `Oops there has been an error: ${error}`;
    
    console.log(data)

  return {
    title : data.title,
    description : data.description,
    author : data.author,
    type : data.type,
    image : data.image,
  }
```

Thank you for your help.

I tried to check the following points:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)

2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks

3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

but could not achieve much.

Comment: "You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks" - Thats what causes the error. Please read rules of [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your code, `getDocumentProps` is not function component (You did not return JSX element) or custom Hook(custom Hook should start name with `use`, for example: `useGetDocumentProps`). It's just javascript function. So you are breaking react hook rules.

In my opinion, you can change the name with `useGetDocumentProps` and use it as custom Hook and return your data and error/loading. And then import in your main Component to get your data like that:

```
import { useGetDocumentProps } from './your custom hook path here'

const YourComponentName = (pageProps) => {
  const { loading, error, title, description, author, type, image } = useGetDocumentProps()

 if (loading) return (<p>Loading...</p>)
 if (error) return (<p>{`Oops there has been an error: ${error}`}</p>)
  
  return (
    <>{'Your logic here with data'}</>
  )
}

export default YourComponentName
```